# Calculate permutation from Factorial representation of the K-th iteration of the N-th permutation

Tags: c++, performance, combinatorics

As a follow of a post I made on the [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2665171/formula-to-get-a-unique-combination-for-n-values-from-0-to-n-1) I wrote out a simple program that computes the K-th permutation from 0 to N-1 where the number of permutations is `N!`. What I was wondering is could I get some pointers on how to improve and re-write the permutation function to be more efficient--e.g. possibly getting rid of the vector and the for-loop to calculate the factorial.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

///<summary>Calculates the permutation of K in range of 0 to N!. (MAX of N = 20--2^61).</summary>
vector<size_t> factorial_permutation(size_t N, uint64_t K) {
    vector<size_t> Perm;

    uint64_t FactN = N,  //Factorial of N
        RmdrK = K, //Remainder of K/(N-1)!
        IterN = N, //Downward iterator for N
        PostK; //The factorial position of K for each sub permutation.

    for(uint64_t I = N-1; I > 1; I--)
        FactN *= I;
    for (uint64_t I = 1; I <= N; I++) {
        FactN /= IterN--;
        PostK = RmdrK / FactN;
        RmdrK = RmdrK - (PostK * FactN);
        Perm.push_back(PostK);
    }

    return Perm;
}

int main() {
    size_t N = 0;
    uint64_t K = 0;
    vector<size_t> c = factorial_permutation(N, K);
    vector<size_t> s; //The factorial permutation sequence
    vector<size_t> e; //The permutation built from the factorial sequence

    //Builds the basic order sequence 0 to N-1 before permutation.
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        s.push_back(i);

    //Pushes the final result converted from factorial permutation to real permutation. For each entry of sequence s[c[i]] is an index into e[i] to build the permutation.
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        e.push_back(s[c[i]]);
        s.erase(s.begin() + c[i]);
    }

    // Outputs the final permutation.
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        cout << e[i];

    cin.get();
};
```

The function `factorial_permutation` calculates the factorial representation of K--the K-th iteration--in a sequence from `0 to (N-1)!` possible permutations. The `main()` function does simple conversion from the factorial representation to building the actual sequence. I would like to combine the two and see if I can negate the vectors all together for the sake of performance.

I'm also aware that I can remove the vector in `factorial_permutation` by using a basic array, but I can't seem to negate the one in the `main()` function.

Comment: Any particular C++ standard you are using for this? C++11/14/17?

Comment: Doesn't matter. For sake of reference, C++17.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The loop

  ```
  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
      s.push_back(i);
  ```

  is idiomatically expressed as `std::iota(s.begin(), s.end(), 0)` (you'd need to `#include <numeric>`).
- A **no naked loops** principle demands giving a name to the

  ```
      for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
          e.push_back(s[c[i]]);
          s.erase(s.begin() + c[i]);
      }
  ```

  loop. It surely represents an important algorithm. What exactly does it do?

  In any case, the `s` and `e` vectors shall not be exposed to the client.
- Computing factorials restricts the utility of the code to `N < 21` (`21! = 0x2_c507_7d36_b8c4_0000` doesn't fit in 64 bits). Unfortunately you cannot even express `K` within `uint64_t` limits for larger `N`. Consider `BigInteger`.
- It is possible to avoid factorials (as well as ancillary vectors) by working other way around. Consider a pseudocode:

  ```
      while N > 0:
          index = K % N
          swap a[N-1] with a[index]
          K /= N
          N -= 1
  ```

  While correct, it doesn't produce the same `K`'th permutation as your code does. May I suggest changing it to produce the correct sequence as an exercise?

PS: a mandatory warning on [using namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: `std::iota()` isn't a *direct* replacement there - it's a shame there's no `std::iota_n` that could take a back-insert iterator.

Comment: Thank you for the answer I've revised my code to include comments. My apologies it's not the best code/commented. I mocked it up really quick.

Comment: @vnp unfortunately `std:iota()` doesn't work here if `s` is a length of 0. Unless I defined `s` as `vector<uint64_t> s(N);` which might save some performance, if any.

Comment: @vnp I'll try out your changes here and get back to you. I don't care how it produces the permutations, just that it produces them faster and without duplicates and covers the `N!` number of permutations requirements.